# Cron & Virtualenv : Cron does not run a python script that requires a virtualenv

Tags: cron, virtualenv, pythonbrew

**EDIT 2** 27/06/2013: The problem was a silly mistake unrelated to venv and cron.
Running venv from cron with the same user that created the venv works great using the activate desscribed below.

**EDIT** 25/06/2013: Since nohup.out is unchanged after the cron runs, I suspect the problem is in the use of virtualenv.
The cron is set with the same user than the one running the script from the command line.

---

I have written a script to activate venv then run a python script. It runs perfectly from the command line, when I do

```
nohup /home/heyheyhey/run.sh &
```

However, for some black magic reasons, the python part does not run from cron:

```
0 4 * * * /home/heyheyhey/run.sh &
```

Content of run.sh:

```
#! /bin/bash
cd /home/heyheyhey
. /home/heyheyhey/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.2/venvname/bin/activate 2> error.log
python /home/heyheyhey/top.py 2> error.log
bzip2 -c "Exporter.csv" > "extraction.csv.bz2"
```

The run.sh executes since the output compressed file is created.
However the python script does not work since the Exporter.csv is not updated and I do not see activity into the log file.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There's no need to use `nohup` or `&` in a cron job. `nohup` isn't necessary because there's no terminal to disconnect, and `&` isn't needed because everything in cron is effectively in the background.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but I tried with and without nohup and there are no differences, the python script still does not run!

Comment: I never said it would make a difference, I just said it's not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The environment of a cron job is often different from the environment you see
when you're logged into an interactive shell.  In particular, you might want to
check whether the python interpreter is on the $PATH for the cron job.  If your
python program reads any environment variables, you should check those too, to
ensure they're set as expected under cron.

Comment: Also make sure to check `nohup.out`, the logfile that `nohup` redirects stdout/stderr to. It probably has a bunch of error messages.

Comment: Actually, at least on OS X, `nohup` itself is not in the default path for cron jobs.

Comment: Good idea, but nohup.out has not changed since the last time I ran the script (directly from the command line)

Comment: I suspect the problem is into the use of virtualenv with my cron user maybe? However, the cron is set with the same user I run the script in the terminal